# Sufficient condition for an infinite series to be zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Consider an infinite power series $f(x):= \Sigma_{i=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ where $a_n$ are any complex numbers. In particular, we make no assumption on $a_n$ to ensure the series converge in any neighborhood of 0 and the notation $f(x)$ is just formal. Suppose now the series satisfy that $f(1/k)=0$ for all positive natural number $k$, meaning if we plug in $1/k$ for $x$ the infinite sum converges to $0$. Can we conclude that $a_n=0$ for all $n$? If not, what is a counter-example? Thank you!

Comment: The fact that plugging in _some_ nonzero number $1/k$ gives a convergent series _automatically_ limits the coefficient growth, and thereby ensures that the series does converge in a neighbourhood of $0$ (namely for all $x$ with $|x|<\frac1k$). So taking care to not assume any convergence is (in a very gross way) spoiled by the later assumption.

Answer (score 10):

If $f(z)$ converges for each $\frac1k$ it must have a radius of converges of at least 1. Hence, $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0$.  There is a standard theorem in complex analysis which states that if the set of zeros of a holomorphic function contains a limit point, then the function must be identically zero.

Edit: I should add that $f$ holomophic implies it is continuous and hence $f(0)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f\left(\frac1k\right)=0$. Hence, the set of zeros does contain a limit point.

Comment: You took the words right out of my mouth. +1.